# Jquery add text after a multi special character

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, replace

i have a string that i want add ',' to end of every '}'
i used replace for do that but it can just add one ',' to end of '}'

```
var s = '[{"codemeli":"2596212109"}{"codemeli":"1234567890"}{"codemeli":"9874563211"}{"codemeli":"2654897125"}]'
alert(s.replace("}", "},"))
```

the result that alert show:

```
[{"codemeli":"2596212109"},{"codemeli":"1234567890"}{"codemeli":"9874563211"}{"codemeli":"2654897125"}]
```

how can add ',' after all of '}'

i want the result like that:

```
[{"codemeli":"2596212109"},{"codemeli":"1234567890"},{"codemeli":"9874563211"},{"codemeli":"2654897125"}]
```

Comment: This seems like an XY Problem. What code is generating the JSON string? It seems like it is being appended using `+=` instead of `.push`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you'd avoid generating the incorrect string in the first place.

```
var a = [
   '{"codemeli":"2596212109"}',
   '{"codemeli":"1234567890"}',
   '{"codemeli":"9874563211"}',
   '{"codemeli":"2654897125"}'
];

var s = "[" + a.join(",") + "]";
```

Or better yet,

```
var a = [
   { "codemeli": "2596212109" },
   { "codemeli": "1234567890" },
   { "codemeli": "9874563211" },
   { "codemeli": "2654897125" }
];

var s = JSON.stringify(a);
```

But let's say you get the string as is from some third party. You could use `String.replace` as follows:

```
s.replace(/\}\{/g, "},{");
```

The `g` causes all instances to be replaced.